# dotnet-install.sh not adding dotnet command on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am not a Linux user so this might be a easy fix but I have tried the following:

1. first I install it using the command `curl -sSL https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.sh | bash /dev/stdin` for which I get the following result:

> dotnet-install: .NET Core SDK version 2.1.403 is already installed.
>    dotnet-install: Adding to current process PATH:
>    `/home/<!username!>/.dotnet`. Note: This change will be visible only when sourcing script.
>           dotnet-install: Installation finished successfully.

2. I do `. ~/.profile` to reload the profile,
   but even after this when I run `dotnet` I get the following error:

> Command 'dotnet' not found, but can be installed with:
>   sudo snap install dotnet-sdk`

I was expecting the script to do everything and make `dotnet` available.

Comment: So, did you run `sudo snap install dotnet-sdk`?

Comment: @miken32 no I did not try that. Because from what I read in the doc, the script was suppose to do it already.

Comment: The Snap package doesn't seem to work right now anyway: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-73736#focus=Comments-27-5731409.0-0

Answer (score 26, accepted):

TLDR: `curl | bash` can not modify `PATH` so it will not add `dotnet` to your `PATH`. You need to add `dotnet` to your path manually. Add `export PATH="$PATH:/home/<!username!>/.dotnet"` to your `~/.profile` (or `~/.bashrc` or equivalent) and log out and log back in.

Long version:

When you run a command in the shell (for example, bash), the shell tries to find an executible with the name in the all the paths listed in the environment variable `PATH`. `PATH` is generally set to something like `/bin:/usr/bin`. So when you type a command like `curl`, your shell looks in both `/bin` and `/usr/bin` for an executible file named `curl`.

You can see what your `PATH` is by doing `env | grep PATH` or `echo $PATH`.

The other important piece of information is how environment variables propagate. It's quite simple, actually:

1. A program (or process) can only modify its own set of environment variables.
2. Any child processes that a process creates inherit its environment variables.

What this means is that a program that you execute can not modify the environment variables of another random program. The shell actually provides a special command, `export` to set its own environment variables (and any child processes it later creates will inherit those).

Note the output at the end of step 1.

> Note: This change will be visible only when sourcing script.

If you run `curl | bash`, it runs `bash` as a child process. That child process can not modify the environment variables of the program that started it (the shell that invoked `curl | bash`). So it can not modify `PATH` to add the location of `dotnet` to it. It even (helpfully) tells you that it can't.

In step 2, you are reloading `~/.profile`. But does it contain any commands to add `dotnet` to `PATH`? I dont think so. I know the dotnet-install.sh script has not historically added it. You need to add a line like

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/<!username!>/.dotnet"
```

To your `~/.profile` (or `~/.bashrc`, or equivalent) manually.

Actually, I would write it as follows to make the change more portable to other users:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.dotnet"
```

Comment: Rather than logging out you could instead run `source ~/.zshrc` or whatever your shell of choice is.

Comment: what if there is no $HOME/.dotnet file?

Comment: If there's no `$HOME/.dotnet`, that generally means `dotnet-install.sh` didn't work correctly. Can you post it as a new question with output of running the command?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer of [omajid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3561275/omajid) is simply this:

If you get `command not found` error even though you installed by following Microsoft's official page and you want to run dotnet from command line then run following command line in the terminal.

```
echo $'\n# DOTNET ENVINRONMET PATH VARIABLE\nexport DOTNET_ROOT=$HOME/dotnet/\nexport PATH=$PATH:$HOME/dotnet/' >> $HOME/.bashrc
```

The above command adds the required commands (Same command is available in official microsoft dotnet download [page](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-8.0.101-linux-x64-binaries) as well) easly to be run dotnet in terminal session.

Now log out from your session and re-login. After that you should be able to access dotnet through command line.

Answer (score -2):

Try running this again:

```sh
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.2
```